# Problem with activated route in case of replacing existing ProductListComponent

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I tried to replace `ProductListComponent` with custom. The problem is when I go to url, e.g. `http://localhost:4200/c/584`, activated route doesn't have any params.. But I'm expecting `categoryCode` or `brandCode`. What problem is?

Component code:

```
export class CustomProductListComponent extends ProductListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub: Subscription;
  constructor(..) {..}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.activeFacetValueCode = params.categoryCode || params.brandCode;
    });
    super.ngOnInit();
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub) {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Config:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        CMSProductListComponent: {
          component: CustomProductListComponent
        },
        ProductRefinementComponent: {
          component: CustomProductFacetNavigationComponent
        }
      }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `Subscription` object by `ProductListComponentService` call for getting active route data.